# Is there a better way to display the value of environment variables inside a makefile command?

Tags: makefile, environment-variables, echo

I am doing deploys from specific machines. These are the same machines
being used for development. This situation can cause some problems
since the environment variables desired for deploys can be different
from the ones to be used for development!

When the engineer is developing, it is useful to have a `.zshrc` file with stuff like:

```
export TFR_RELEASE="my-instance-for-development"
export TFR_DEV="my-instance-for-development"
```

However, the instance for the deploy is a different one!

The project already has a `makefile` to help streamline things. One of
the `make` commands is `make clean`:

```bash
clean:
    rm -rf .shadow-cljs
    rm -rf node_modules
    rm -rf target
    rm -rf public/js
```

In order to make the developer aware on which instance is being used, I decided to add the last two lines:

```bash
clean:
    rm -rf .shadow-cljs
    rm -rf node_modules
    rm -rf target
    rm -rf public/js
    echo "TFR_DEV" "$(TFR_DEV)"  
    echo "TFR_RELEASE" "$(TFR_RELEASE)"
```

After executing `$ make clean`, the terminal returns:

```bash
➜  make clean
rm -rf .shadow-cljs
rm -rf node_modules
rm -rf target
rm -rf public/js
echo "TFR_DEV" "my-instance-for-development"
TFR_DEV my-instance-for-development
echo "TFR_RELEASE" "my-instance-for-development"
TFR_RELEASE my-instance-for-development"
```

If feels a bit repetitive the display of the relevant information...
Since the *value* of the *variable* is being evaluated on the
terminal's "prompt" and on the terminal's "answer".

Is there a better way to "print" it?

My approach **does not** feel elegant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you precede receipt commands with @, they will no show up. Only the result.

```
clean:
    rm -rf .shadow-cljs
    rm -rf node_modules
    rm -rf target
    rm -rf public/js
    @echo "TFR_DEV" "$(TFR_DEV)"  
    @echo "TFR_RELEASE" "$(TFR_RELEASE)"
```

Comment: Thanks. But, there is no `@` in your answer. Maybe you forgot it?

Comment: Sorry. Now corrected.

Answer (score 1):

If the values live in the environment, you could use shell variables instead of Make variables:

```
clean:
    echo "$$TFR_DEV"
    echo "$$TFR_RELEASE"
```

printing

```bash
$ make clean
echo "$TFR_DEV"
my-instance-for-development
echo "$TFR_RELEASE"
my-instance-for-development
```